# Asterisk - click2call Java works but takes 2 steps

Tags: java, asterisk, asterisk-java

I've implemented a Java method (using Asterisk-Java library) that initiates a call between two users. Alice is the caller and bob the receiver.
It works but I don't know why, it's doing it in 2 steps :

1. Alice receives a call from herself.
2. If Alice picks up the call then the call between her and Bob is launched. (= Alice has to click on "Accept the call" so that the call to Bob is eventually made.

Any idea why Alice receives a call from herself first?

Here's my code :

```
public void call(final String user, final String exten) throws IOException, AuthenticationFailedException, TimeoutException {
    OriginateAction originateAction;
    ManagerResponse originateResponse;

    originateAction = new OriginateAction();
    originateAction.setChannel("SIP/" + user);
    originateAction.setContext("work");
    originateAction.setExten(exten);
    originateAction.setPriority(new Integer(1));
    originateAction.setTimeout(new Long(30000));

    // connect to Asterisk and log in
    managerConnection.login();

    // send the originate action and wait for a maximum of 30 seconds for Asterisk to send a reply
    originateResponse = managerConnection.sendAction(originateAction, 30000);

    // and finally log off and disconnect
    managerConnection.logoff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
originateAction.setChannel("SIP/" + user);
```

This action launched first.

If you need other order, you shoudl do it other order.

You can do dial via Local/ channel.

This question was answered by me in last month 4 or 5 times.

For more info see other similar questions.